Using "x AND y" instead of "x OR y" when using --grep twice in git-log
I'm trying to find commits whose commit message includes both key words "x" and "y". I've tried using git log --grep="x" --grep="y", and while this does include all commits with X and Y, it also includes those with just X or just Y.
Is there a way to grep by two expressions and inlcude only those which match both?

Have a look at git log --help. What you want seems to be the option listed right below --grep, which is --all-match. Alternatively you can use regex in the pattern. E.g.: Looking for commits with "analysis notebook" in them I can use "analysis * notebook" and get what I want, or the two words as separate grep patterns, joined with --all-match

You need the --all-match flag:
git log --grep="x" --grep="y" --all-match

